# NLTK: Adding production rules to already existing grammar

Tags: python, parsing, nltk

I'm reading my FCFG grammar from a file and want to add more production rules at Run-Time to that grammar. I could always take the sting representation of my grammar and concatenate new rules, but I'm looking for something more elegant, like

```
grammar.add_rule.fromstring('PropN -> David')
```

How(if possible) can it be done using nltk. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Production](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/15e7f74874cf562a44747957f006cf30869a15cd/nltk/grammar.py#L261) class of nltk to create new productions and append them to the list of rules.

```
lhs = nltk.grammar.Nonterminal('PropN')
rhs = nltk.grammar.Nonterminal('David')
new_production = nltk.grammar.Production(lhs, [rhs])
rules = grammar.productions()
rules.append(new_production)
```

Comment: If you already got a list of productions, you can run through the list for calling its Nonterminal class, e.g. lhs = production.lhs()